# Fixed divs, scrolling in one direction only ("How to do rulers on canvas?")

Tags: html, css

We've got a frame div that acts as scrollbox for a "canvas" div of arbitrary size (not an actual canvas element, it may be anything, e.g. a div with an image inside). Inside that frame div, two rulers should be tacked to the left and bottom border, and those rulers should scroll with the canvas: the left ruler should scroll vertically with the canvas and the bottom ruler should scroll horizontally with the canvas, but both should stay tacked at their respective frame border.

Our approach until now works, IF the canvas and left ruler is higher than the frame:

```css
#frame {
  margin: 2rem;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}
#canvas {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #444, #ccc);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
}
#leftRuler {
  width: 40px;
  height: 400px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #c00, #400);
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
}
#bottomRuler {
  width: 800px;
  height: 40px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #00c, #004);
  position: sticky;
  bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="frame">
  <div id="canvas">
  </div>
  <div id="leftRuler">
  </div>
  <div id="bottomRuler">
  </div>
</div>
```

But as soon as the canvas and left ruler becomes smaller than the frame, the bottom ruler loses its stickyness (only differences in code are the heights of frame, canvas and left ruler). Please note the gap between the blue bar and the lower horizontal scrollbar here:

```css
    #frame {
      margin: 2rem;
      overflow: auto;
      position: relative;
      width: 400px;
      height: 300px;
    }
    #canvas {
      width: 800px;
      height: 200px;
      background: linear-gradient(135deg, #444, #ccc);
      overflow: hidden;
      position: absolute;
      top:0;
      left:0;
      bottom:0;
      right:0;
    }
    #leftRuler {
      width: 40px;
      height: 200px;
      background: linear-gradient(45deg, #c00, #400);
      position: sticky;
      left: 0;
    }
    #bottomRuler {
      width: 800px;
      height: 40px;
      background: linear-gradient(45deg, #00c, #004);
      position: sticky;
      bottom:0;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="frame">
      <div id="canvas">
      </div>
      <div id="leftRuler">
      </div>
      <div id="bottomRuler">
      </div>
    </div>
```

We can't seem to find a robust solution for this problem. Does anybody have an idea for a robust, preferably CSS-only solution? Ideally, it should work without a fixed height on the left ruler (it should be possible to let the contents of the left ruler determine its height).

We already tried various other approaches, including using `position:fixed` or messing around with lots of relative, absolute and fixed divs ... the current code above is only the approach that worked best up until now.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. I've put more definite linear gradients into the rulers and the content to assure myself that movement is happening in the right directions. The bottom ruler is staying stuck to the bottom and is scrolling left-right OK. I'm using Edge/Chrome on Windows 10. What system are you using.

Comment: @AHaworth FF and Chrome on Windows. The problem is that in the second example, the lower ruler is in some distance from the scrollbar.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks. We need to move the whole lot down then (I assume you don't want a gap between the rulers and the content?)

Comment: @AHaworth exactly. I want the gap between the canvas div and the ruler (if the canvas is smaller than the frame) or no gap at all (if the canvas is bigger than the frame).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the bottom ruler is not at the bottom (i.e. not in its stuck position) it has the equivalent of position relative. The canvas has position absolute so does not influence this but the left ruler has position sticky. This means its height influences where the following element is positioned.

One way to get the bottom ruler properly positioned is to make it be in its stuck position from the start. When the canvas height is greater than the frame height this happens, as the first snippet in the question shows. When the canvas (and therefore the left ruler which has the same height) is shorter than the frame the bottom ruler is placed immediately below it.

If we make the left ruler have the same height as the frame then the bottom ruler will always be in its stuck position. We still need the left ruler to only show its 'markings' (the linear gradient in this example) for just the height of the canvas. This snippet does this by setting the size of the left ruler background accordingly. Click a button to alter canvas height.

```css
#frame {
  margin: 2rem;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  --ch: 200px;
  /* height of canvas */
  height: 300px;
}

#canvas {
  width: 800px;
  height: var(--ch);
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #444, #ccc);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#leftRuler {
  width: 40px;
  height: max(var(--ch), calc(100% - 40px));
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #c00, #400);
  background-size: 100% var(--ch);
  background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
}

#bottomRuler {
  width: 800px;
  height: 40px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #00c, #004);
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="frame">
  <div id="canvas">
  </div>
  <div id="leftRuler">
  </div>
  <div id="bottomRuler">
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="document.querySelector('#frame').style.setProperty('--ch', '200px');">Canvas height 200px</button>
<button onclick="document.querySelector('#frame').style.setProperty('--ch', '400px');">Canvas height 400px</button>
```

Comment: This does look very good, we'll be testing it! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks again for that hint. We tested it and it's even more robust than we hoped for.